# ServiceStack v3 client exception

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm having trouble with my ServiceStack web service. I had to move from v4 to v3 upon discovering the cost implication -- and on the service side this is fine. (I only mention this as it may be relevant somehow).

In my C# client code, however, I am now receiving an exception and I have no idea what's wrong.

```
 var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://192.168.0.60:7070/api/");

        WpDataRestService.ServiceModel.GetClientDataResponse response = client
            .Get(new ServiceModel.GetClientData {
                AccountId = accountId,
                Date = versionDate
            });

return response.Results;
```

When this code is run, I get the exception:

> WebServiceException was unhandled - Not Found

.. but only after 335 calls to this piece of code. This is being run in a loop where I am retrieving (mostly cached) data about clients to build a report. For some reason, on the 336th iteration I get the 404 error.

Is there some kind of connection being closed or something along those lines that could account for this? Or are the number of calls in some way causing an exception?

Comment: When this error occurs, can you issue a request ok using Fiddler/Postman and get the same error, or is it something different? Are you spinning up a new client for each request, or re-using the same client?

Comment: It's a new client for each request; I've also tried to reuse the same one but get the same result. I can call the same client data up via URL in a browser, so I know the data itself is not in some way 'wrong'.. I'm installing Fiddler just now to check this out as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the DateTime value being passed into the webservice was invalid for one of the loop iterations, for some reason. Corrected now.

Comment: Great that it works... odd that it was still accepted by V4 of the framework though (or was it?)

Comment: I had thought that it was; but perhaps I didn't get to this particular record in the first set of tests. For now I'll assume not. Thanks for your help.